# Generate infinite list from function results

Tags: algorithm, haskell, memoization

I have a function that takes an integer and returns a list of integers.

How do I efficiently map this function to an initial integer, then for each item of the resulting list that has not be previously mapped, apply the same function and essentially generate an infinite list.

E.g.

```
f :: Int -> [Int]
f 0 = [1,2]++(f 1)++(f 2)
```

Additionally, I need to be able to index the resulting list up to 10E10. How would this be optimised? memoization?

Comment: This might be a case of an example that isn't thought out, but this definition isn't valid. `f` is *only* defined for 0; `f 1` and `f 2` aren't defined at all. You might want to read about `Data.List.unfoldr`.

Comment: @chepner I can add more examples, but I didn't want to define more than what was necessary to understand the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a breadth-first search.  The basic idiom goes like this:

```
bfs :: (a -> [a]) -> [a] -> [a]
bfs f xs = xs ++ bfs f (concatMap f xs)
```

Notice how we keep the current "state" in the argument `xs`, output it and then recursively call with a new state which is `f` applied to each element of the input state.

If you want to filter out elements you haven't seen before, you need to also pass along some extra state keeping track of which elements you've seen, e.g. a `Data.Set`, and adjust the algorithm accordingly.  I'll leave that bit to you because I'm an irritating pedagogue.

Comment: Thanks, this is very similar to what I came up with, didn't realise it was a bfs. But is there any optimization possible? currently getting the value at 10E6 for the resulting list takes about 20s on my machine.

Comment: If there are any repeated values, pruning them will help immensely, if you're not already doing that.  Breadth-first search also ought to parallelize well, but getting the tuning right can be tricky (and I'm not really an expert in that -- might be fodder for another SO question).  Otherwise I'd look for some mathematical structure  in the function you are searching that you can leverage (e.g. if it always computes two values, you can calculate the exact expression for the 10e6th element using some logarithms or something).

Comment: Oh, a random thought, you might try strict indexing ``ix 0 (x:xs) = x; ix n (x:xs) = x `seq` ix (n-1) xs`` to get the nth element.  If the function is very simple, you might be suffering from some thunk buildup.  And of course compile your code with `-O` as always.